# How can I relate my login tables to other tables in my SQL Server database?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, winforms

I currently have one table in SQL Server 2017 Express, I am using SSMS, can anyone explain how to relate my tables to other tables like orders, products, or you can have an unrelated table in the database?

Like a separate login table with no relation just to authenticate my Windows Forms application?

Comment: [Foreign Key Constraint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/create-foreign-key-relationships?view=sql-server-2017) would be worth looking into

Comment: Why do you need the Login table to have relationship with other? Is there a logical reason to have the relationship?

Comment: scsimon , is it possible to have an unrelated table in my database

Comment: Absolutely, they are all *unrelated* until you *relate them*. There's a ton of information out there on ERD, etc.

Comment: Dan Hunex , Yes I Want To Store UserLogs For The Operation users perform , i will relate that table with my users obviously

Comment: Actually I Missed The Actuall Question , I Have Winform Application For The POS System , Now What I Am Doing Is Restricting Access To Other Forms By Having A Login Form In The Startup Which Validates User Credentials , The Question Is Do I have To Represent That In The ERD Or The Table Relation That I Will Give Access To Authorized USers , Or It is just fine to have an unrelated users table except for the userlogs that i need to relate to ??

Comment: i hope you understand my question ??

Comment: Instead of putting your question in the comments you should [edit] your post and put this in the body.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the instruction provided [here](https://www.quackit.com/sql_server/sql_server_2016/tutorial/create_a_relationship_in_sql_server_2016.cfm) to create a foreign key in SSMS.